# Formatting actual date with jQuery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I created a form for a date range using jQuery UI Datepicker.

```
 <form action="activity_report_date_range.php" method="GET" name="search_reporting" id="search_reporting"><br />
    <label for="from">Start Date:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from"><br><br>
    <label for="to">Last Date:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
  <input style="margin-bottom: 20px" type="submit" name="submit_search" id="submit" value="Search" placeholder="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm using Google hosted jQuery UI. Everything seems to be working fine, but I want to format the date with dashes, instead of forward slashes.

For example,

I'd like to have the date be input as: 2014-11-05 (Y-m-d) rather than what it currently is populating, 11/05/2014

The "dashes" and date format y-m-d is what i'm looking for. Can't seem to get it. Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tz53ujqo/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: You can call the dateformat like this:

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tz53ujqo/2/